# CONVERT TIMES in HighChart

Tags: javascript, datetime, highcharts

I am using High charts to compare waiting time with discharge times for each patient.

For example:

```
Patient ID   Expected Time    Waiting Time
2            2 hours          1 hour
```

I have a connection to a database to get these times:

```
$query2 = "SELECT PatientID,Forename, Patient.Illness, Patient.Priority, Arrival_time, MY_TIME() AS now, ABS( TIMEDIFF( MY_TIME( ) , Arrival_time ) ) AS Waiting_Time, TIME_TO_SEC( Expected_time) as Expected_time , TIME_TO_SEC( Discharge_time )  as Discharge_time, Examined
FROM Patient, priority_time
WHERE Patient.Illness = priority_time.Illness
AND Patient.Priority = priority_time.Priority;";
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2) or die("Invalid query: ".$query2);
```

I want to display the Patient ID on X axis and Waiting Time on Y axis.

Issues:

```
Converting Time to display in this format: hours: minutes: seconds on Y axis.
```

Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function drawChart(){
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'divforchart',
                    type:'column',
                },
                xAxis: {
                    name:'patients',
                    categories: ['Juan','Pepe','Paco']
                },
                yAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime'
                },

                series: [
                    {
                        name: 'Arrival time',
                        data: [
                            ['Juan',Date.UTC(2012,4,18,11,0)], 
                            ['Pepe',Date.UTC(2012,4,18,11,0)], 
                            ['Paco',Date.UTC(2012,4,18,11,0)] 
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Expected time',
                        data: [
                            ['Juan',Date.UTC(2012,4,18,12,00)], 
                            ['Pepe',Date.UTC(2012,4,18,13,00)], 
                            ['Paco',Date.UTC(2012,4,18,11,15)]
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            });
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="drawChart()">
     <div id="divforchart" style="height: 400px"></div>
    </body>
```

EDIT: 
[image: Visualization]

Comment: Change in your data from 'Juan', 'Pepe', 'Paco' to index of category, so: `data: [
                            [0,Date.UTC(2012,4,18,12,00)], 
                            [1,Date.UTC(2012,4,18,13,00)], 
                            [2,Date.UTC(2012,4,18,11,15)]
                        ]`

Comment: Patient ID is not displaying on X axis, Time is not displaying on Y axis and not converting to show TIMES. Please see screen shot attached.

Comment: Set threshold for column series, or min for yAxis. Columns always starts from 0, which in dateTime axis means from 1970 year. Regarding patients - I can see some patientID - while in the code I can see categories properly set.

Comment: time should be displaying the this format: hours: minutes: seconds. Currently, the time is displaying in milliseconds